# How to write this mongodb near query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

```
db.places.find(
   {
     location:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            $minDistance: 1000,
            $maxDistance: 5000
          }
       }
   }
)
```

Comment: {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f0237bdcb57b0146028b79d"
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-79.3832, 43.6]
  }
  // other fields
}.      If I have this data on my mongodb collection distance .

Comment: you use pure mongo driver or some orm like - mongoose?